# Periphrastic verb forms in Gothic

Tags: historical-linguistics, verbs, perfect, standard-average-european, gothic

What periphrastic verb form are attested in the Gothic language, the oldest Germanic language we have substantial records from?

Skimming through a [grammar of Gothic](https://archive.org/details/gotischegrammat02braugoog) I found that for the past tense passive a periphrastic construction was used (which is remarkably identical to the Modern German one, using the Gothic cognate of Modern German *werden* and the past participle; Gothic also has a be passive comparable to the English one).

I have not found any traces of a *have perfect* but this may just be outside the scope of the grammar and is maybe attested in the Gothic corpus (similarly, short Latin grammars probably don't mention *probatum habeo* as a periphrastic perfect active form).

Are there periphrastic verb form other than the passive I have already mentioned attested in the corpus of Gothic text we have?

This question is inspired by [Where did the use of the two auxiliaries in the Romance languages come from?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27252/where-did-the-use-of-the-two-auxiliaries-in-the-romance-languages-come-from) and its answers and comments.

Comment: Check German translations of the New Testament for potential cognates. Practically all the Gothic we have is bible translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michail Kotin - it's worth checking out his monograph *Gotisch
Im (diachronischen und typologischen) Vergleich* ([Kotin 2012](https://www.winter-verlag.de/de/detail/978-3-8253-5991-1/Kotin_Gotisch_Im_diachronischen_Vergleich/)) - argues that

> "Gothic **does not have** the construction with have and past participle, which was the main indicator of the latest analytic form in Western Germanic encoding perfect."